# Why doesn't karma-cli accept files as command line argument?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm using the config from my project but would like to run karma just for one specific test script one time. I don't want to have to create a whole new config file just for this case and would prefer just passing in the script I want run (so basically telling karma to use `files: ['myTest.js']`.

But there don't seem to be any options for that AFAICT in the docs. Why would this be missing? It seems like a fundamental feature IMO.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

in `karma.conf` something like that:

```
function mergeFilesWithArgv(staticFiles) {

    var source = staticFiles, argv = process.argv;

    argv.forEach(function (arg) {
        var index = arg.indexOf('--check=');
        if (index !== -1) {
            source.push(arg.substring(8));
        }
    });

    return source;

}

config.set({

    ...

    files: mergeFilesWithArgv([
        'js_src/tests/*.test.js'
    ]),
    ...

});
```

use: `karma start --check='./path/to/file.js'`

or for multiple files: `karma start --check='./path/to/file.js' --check='/another/path/to/another/file.js'`